# Stuck on Grade 11 Computer Science Activity in Python

Tags: python, function, debugging

This is just a Grade 11 student getting into coding. I was working on this project where I had to create functions that will print out asterisks of any given height or width.

It took me like 10 minutes to almost get it done, but I can't get rid of the "None" sign that follows right after the asterisk. I tried returning "" and if-else, but I'm still stuck.

[image]

**This is my code for now:**

```
def drawLine (Width):
    if x >= 1:
        for i in range (0, x): 
            print ('*'),
      
def control (Height):
    if y >= 1:
        for i in range (0, y):
            print drawLine(x)

y = input('Height: ')
x = input('Width: ')

control (y)
```

Screenshot([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hp9b.png))

Comment: Because functions return `none` and you are printing a function call, all you should need to do is remove the print from in front of `print drawline....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran and checked solution.

```
y = int(input('Height: '))
x = int(input('Width: '))

if x >= 1 and y >= 1:
    str = "* " * x  # multiply the string by x
    for i in range(0, y):
        print(str)  # vertically print the generated string
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually works out pretty nice. I would've never got it.. Thanks a lot again!! :)

Comment: No worries. Best of luck programming!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
def drawLine (Width):
if x >= 1:
    for i in range (0, x): 
        print ('*',end=" ")
    print()
  
def control (Height):
    if y >= 1:
        for i in range (0, y):
            drawLine(x)

y = int(input('Height: '))
x = int(input('Width: '))

control (y)
```

Comment: This works really nice in PythonTutor but for some reason I'm only able to use something called Wing IDE and that apparently doesn't like the 4th line - calls it invalid syntax - string. I think there's something wrong with the software I'm using.. Thank you so much anyways!! :)